# Find number of function parameters and their names

Tags: javascript, python

I have code like this in JavaScript:

```
function func(param1, param2) {}

console.log(func.length); // 2

var getParamNames = require('get-parameter-names');
console.log(getParamNames(func)); // ['param1', 'param2']
```

How would you write this in Python, to which I am new?

Comment: It’s worth reading the docs on the stdlib `inspect` module (linked in srig’s answer). While everything it does can be done more directly, it makes 95% of the reflection anyone will ever need a whole lot simpler (as well as taking care of edge cases, working across different Python versions/implementations, etc.). And its documentation is often the best place to find out how to do things directly even when you for some reason don’t want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you could get a similar output with [inspect.signature().parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature).

```
from inspect import signature

def func(param1, param2):
    pass

print(len(signature(func).parameters.keys()))
# 2

def get_param_names(yourfunc):
    return list(signature(yourfunc).parameters.keys())

print(get_param_names(func))
# ['param1', 'param2']
```

Answer (score 1):

With `your_function.__code__.co_varnames` you get a tuple of parameters names.

Example:

```
def count_params(func):
    return len(func.__code__.co_varnames)

def test(param1, param2):
    pass

print(count_params(test)) # 2
```

Comment: It’s definitely worth knowing how to do this, but it’s much better to use `inspect` in most cases. That way, it works with introspectable builtins, and in other Python implementations, and it makes it easier to distinguish `*args` from individual parameters, and so on.